# Data migration from CockroachDB to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-migration, pg-dump, cockroachdb

I am trying to migrate my CockroachDB into PostgreSQL.

I have dumps of CockroachDB data in SQL format like "booking.sql".

I tried many ways ways to solve this problem:

1. tried direct import of dump file using psql, but since the dump file was of CockroachDB it is showing some syntactical error
2. my second plan was to restore the dump file back into CockroachDB system and try running pgdump from there. But I am not able to restore the database in CockroachDB.

`ERROR: failed to open backup storage location: unsupported storage scheme: "" - refer to docs to find supported storage schemes`

I tried doing again with `import` statement from CockroachDB, but that was of no use.

Answer (score 1):

for exporting data from cockroachDB there are some limitations. you can't export your data into SQL directly in new versions.
the first way of exporting is using the `cockroach dump` command, but it's been deprecated from version 20.2 so if you are using a newer version, this won't work.

```
cockroach dump <database> <table> <table...> <flags>
```

sample:

```
cockroach dump startrek --insecure --user=maxroach > backup.sql
```

in new versions, you can export your data into CSV files using SQL commands like `EXPORT`

```
EXPORT DATABASE bank INTO 's3://{BUCKET NAME}/{PATH}?AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID={KEYID}&AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY={SECRET ACCESS KEY}' \ AS OF SYSTEM TIME '-10s';
```

to export into local nodes

```
EXPORT DATABASE bank INTO ('nodelocal://1/{PATH}');
```

the other alternative way of exporting is using database clients such as DBeaver.
you can download and install DBeaver from https://dbeaver.io/download/.
after adding the connection you can export the database from this path Right-click on db>tools>Backup

the fastest and easiest way of exporting is using a database tool like DBeaver.
I hope this answer would have been helpful

Comment: thanks for replay bur actually I already have the backup file all I want to do is migrate all of them into postgresql . 
I tried pg_dumping against cockroach clusture . But it doesnt work for me.
and also tried postgres fdw . But the error shows me I cant import data . Since postgres cant connect to cockroach